# Probability of correctly ordering a 12-word passphrase

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say I give you a set of 12 words which forms a complete passphrase, in a random order.

What is the number of different ways that you can order them? Or in other words, what's the chance of you putting them in the correct order?

Comment: Simply $12!$ , where is the problem ?

Comment: What is a passpharse?

Comment: Peter so you're saying 12 factorial? What's that number expressed in more common language or can you give a breakdown of the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the answer to the first question is

$12! = 12 \times 11 \times 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 479001600$

As for the other question, the probability of getting the passphrase is $\frac{1}{12!} = \frac{1}{479001600} \approx 2.09 \times 10^{-9}$ which means you have a $2.09 \times 10^{-6}\%$ chance of getting the passphrase.